# Get actual Job Name from Program Name column of the results while running sp_whoisactive or sp_who2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql, sp-whoisactive

I am running `sp_whoisactive` on my Prod and offload the data for analysis.

When I run `sp_whoisactive` or `sp_who2` and if there is any SQL Agent Jobs running it would always display the Program Name like SQLAgent - TSQL JobStep (Job 0x984ECB0C94C14943B787BDE548F77311 : Step 1).

I want  the job name to be displayed there instead of those numbers.

I have to  manually copy that value and run it against `select * from msdb..sysjobs where job_id = 0x984ECB0C94C14943B787BDE548F77311`

Can any help me with this.

PS: tried to substring only the hexadecimal and convert it to uniqueidentifier and then run it to on the sysjobs tables as a variable but didn't work.

```
--This is what I tried to do

declare @substring nvarchar(200)   
select @substring = (SUBSTRING(@program,30,34))
select @substring

declare @jobname nvarchar(200) 
select @jobname = (select name from msdb..sysjobs where job_id = convert(uniqueidentifier,@substring))

select @jobname

--Error message

Msg 8169, Level 16, State 2, Line 22
Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you go through a binary 16 before making it uniqueidentifier. You also need a proper format code when decoding the string to binary 16.

Below work for me. You obviously have to work out how to get the
ProgramName for the *right* job into your variable.

```
DECLARE @a varchar(300)

--Get the job id
SET @a = 
(SELECT s.program_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions AS s
WHERE s.program_name LIKE 'SQLAgent - TSQL JobStep%')

--Extract only binary represenation of the job id, as a string
SET @a = SUBSTRING(@a, 30, 34)

--Cast to binary 16 and use the format code 1 for CONVERT
--Then cast that binary 16 to uniqueidentifier
SELECT * FROM msdb..sysjobs WHERE job_id = CAST(CONVERT(binary(16), @a, 1) AS uniqueidentifier)
```

Comment: Thank you very much that worked...

Comment: I have another similar scenario. The Program Name displays the SSIS package name but I want the Job name and Step ID of it. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this easily with `sp_WhoIsActive`.

```
EXEC dbo.sp_WhoIsActive 
    @get_additional_info = 1, 
    @get_task_info = 2;
```

[image: NUTS]

If you click on the `additional_info` column, you'll see this:

[image: NUTS]

You don't explicitly need the `@get_task_info` parameter to retrieve the extra information, it's just a very useful [general combination](http://whoisactive.com/docs/19_whyblocked/).

Comment: Thanks for your insight, Noted.

Comment: I have another similar scenario. The Program Name displays the SSIS package name but I want the Job name and Step ID of it.  I don't see it with  @get_additional_info = 1.

Answer (score 1):

Change the Job_ID in the where clause

```
Select      Name
From        msdb.dbo.sysjobs
Where       master.dbo.fn_VarbinToHexStr(Job_ID) = '0x00000000000000000000000000000000'
```